# Pop without data / push to the current screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i'm trying to pop without return data.
**i have 1 screen that have 4 Bottomnavigator that have 4 layout for each button**

```
      LayoutType.table: (_) => Page1(
          layoutGroup: _layoutGroup, onLayoutToggle: _onLayoutGroupToggle),
      LayoutType.favorite: (_) => Page2(
          layoutGroup: _layoutGroup, onLayoutToggle: _onLayoutGroupToggle),
      LayoutType.menu: (_) => Page3(
          layoutGroup: _layoutGroup, onLayoutToggle: _onLayoutGroupToggle),
      LayoutType.custom: (_) => Page4(
          layoutGroup: _layoutGroup, onLayoutToggle: _onLayoutGroupToggle),
    }[_layoutSelection](context);
```

and in page 3 ,i have a showdialog content with textfield and flatbutton **add** , after i press **add** i need to get back to Page 3 , i try use pop it's work but if i to press **add** button once more it will return the last data that i add .

is there any way to pop wihtout return data?
i try to use Push/PushNamed but it always return to the first screen Page1

```
class MenuPage extends StatefulWidget implements HasLayoutGroup {
  MenuPage({Key key, this.layoutGroup, this.onLayoutToggle}) : super(key: key);
  final LayoutGroup layoutGroup;
  final VoidCallback onLayoutToggle;

  @override
  _MenuPageState createState() => _MenuPageState();
}

class _MenuPageState extends State<MenuPage> {
  double _width;
  double _height;
  String menuName;
  String menuPrice;
  String menuCategory;
  String selectedCategory;
  final formatPrice = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency();
  var menu;
  crudMedthods crudObj = new crudMedthods();
  List _categorymenu = ["Food", "Beverage", "Liquor", "Electricity", "Others"];
  final _textEditingMenu = TextEditingController();
  final _textEditingPrice = TextEditingController();
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownMenuItems;
  String _currentCategory;

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getDropDownMenuItems() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = List();
    for (String catmenu in _categorymenu) {
      items.add(DropdownMenuItem(value: catmenu, child: Text(catmenu)));
    }
    return items;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {

    _textEditingMenu.dispose();
    _textEditingPrice.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _dropDownMenuItems = getDropDownMenuItems();
    _currentCategory = _dropDownMenuItems[0].value;
    crudObj.getDataMenu().then((results) {
      setState(() {
        menu = results;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: _width,
            height: 70,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 2,
              color: Colors.amber[300],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.search),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(295),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
                      onPressed: () {
                        addMenu(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: _width,
            height: 584,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 2,
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent[100],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
              child: Container(child: _menuList()),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // void changedDropDownItem(String selectedCategory) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     _currentCategory = selectedCategory;
  //   });
  // }

  Future<bool> addMenu(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Add Menu', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
            content: Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    controller: _textEditingMenu,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Menu Name'),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      this.menuName = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _textEditingPrice,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Price'),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      this.menuPrice = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    value: _currentCategory,
                    items: _dropDownMenuItems,
                    onChanged: (String value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentCategory = selectedCategory;
                      });
                      menuCategory = value;
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text('Add'),
                        textColor: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (!UtilsImporter()
                              .commanUtils
                              .validateMenuName(menuName)) {
                            UtilsImporter().commanUtils.showToast(
                                UtilsImporter().stringUtils.retrunMenuName,
                                context);
                          } else if (!UtilsImporter()
                              .commanUtils
                              .validateGuestPax(menuPrice)) {
                            UtilsImporter().commanUtils.showToast(
                                UtilsImporter().stringUtils.returnMenuPrice,
                                context);
                          } else if (!UtilsImporter()
                              .commanUtils
                              .validateMenuCategory(menuCategory)) {
                            UtilsImporter().commanUtils.showToast(
                                UtilsImporter().stringUtils.returnMenuCat,
                                context);
                          } else {
                            crudObj.addMenu({
                              'menuName': this.menuName,
                              'menuPrice': this.menuPrice,
                              'menuCategory': this.menuCategory,
                            }).then((result) {
                              // dialogTrigger(context);
                            }).catchError((e) {
                              print(e);
                            });
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            // Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            // Navigator.of(context)
                            //     .pushReplacementNamed('/Dashboard');
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(60),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text('Return'),
                        textColor: Colors.blue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

this is my code from layout Page3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i already know the answer,
it's turn out that The solution for this is to create a new StatefulWidget subclass for my dialog, and put the text editing controllers inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you forgot to dispose your TextField state as suggested in [this link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#create-a-texteditingcontroller). In this case, you have to add

```
    final myController1 = TextEditingController();
    final myController2 = TextEditingController();

     @override
      void dispose() {
        // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the
        // widget tree.
        myController1.dispose();
        myController2.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
```

Comment: i have 2 textfield and 1 dropdownbutton, how to dispose it?

Comment: i already try the code it's works now in my showdialog textfield it show my last data ,but didnt empty it ,

Comment: Please, share your code. Without looking into code, it is quite impossible to find a solution.

Comment: or maybe can i push the back to screen 1 layout Page3? is it possible?